# System.NotSupportedException error

Tags: c#

I'm having a `System.NotsupportedException` error. It says the given path's format is not supported. i'm having this error while adding a music to my game. what should i do to get rid of it?

```
SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer("@\\mymusic.wav");
player.Play();
```

there seems no error while coding but when i'm running the code it is displaying `System.NotsupportedException` error.
can you tell me. am i doing something wrong?

Comment: The path is ill-formed. If the .wav is located at the same folder as the exe, just use `new SoundPlayer("mymusic.wav");`

Comment: What does `@\\` mean?

Comment: it shows that there is no escape character in the string.

Comment: In that case you need the `@` **before** the `"`.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect.

Change

```
SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer("@\\mymusic.wav");
player.Play();
```

...to

```
// move @ to front and outside quotes
SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(@"\mymusic.wav"); 
player.Play();
```

...assuming the .wav file is on the same drive as your app.